# Flex Mobile: changing default application frameRate

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder, flex-mobile

I'm developing a flex game which is really jerky and not smooth at all on mobile devices.
I changed the application frameRate to 60 in my mxml file and it seems to run smoother (but not as it should). Does this have any impact on performance?

Is there any other way to do this? I don't have long and complex operations and I'm saying this because I found some open source libraries through which I can use async threads. But I read that this has downsides also.

I'm really confused because the only objects I have on stage are:
15 Image objects, each one with a Move object attached and an OnClick listener.
4 timers that repeat each 500 ms, 1 second, 2 seconds and 5 seconds.
The longest operation in the listeners and timers is O(n) where n = image count = 15, but most of them are O(1)

All the objects are created on view creationComplete event and I reuse them throughout the entire time.
Memory is managed correctly, I checked using memory profiler.

Can you point me in some directions?

Comment: Increasing frame rate will certainly have a performance impact.  Generally 60fps is the target for games b/c it makes everything feel smooth but you probably don't need it for business applications.

Comment: it is a game. So 60 fps is good?

Comment: Yes, that would be a good target.  But, you may not need it; depending on the type of game and sort.  My own mobile game uses the default Flex framerate.

Comment: Quick performance enhancement would be to reduce your timers to a single one that triggers each 500, 1000, 2000, and 5000ms instead of using 4 different ones for that. Other than that, is there any particular reason for choosing Flex for a game? Stage3D frameworks are your best friend for games.